# How to convert string value to number in playwright automation?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, decimal, playwright

How to change string value extracted from UI into number? I have to perform `Math.round()` function on.
Since `Math.round()` function only works on integers.

`let GE_UI = await this.iGetAtrribute(MyproSelectors.ID_Overridepage, "value"); var GE = Math.round(GE_UI) var aks = parseInt(GE_UI); console.log("ui1 " + GE_UI);`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU3lX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yABYU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Built-In functions like [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert strings in to number and float values

***ParseFloat***

```
function circumference(r) {
  return parseFloat(r) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}

console.log(circumference(4.567));
// Expected output: 28.695307297889173
```

***Number***

```
Number("123"); // returns the number 123
Number("123") === 123; // true
```

***toFixed***  : use this to format an number to an fixed point decimal value and return as STRING.

```
function financial(x) {
  return Number.parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(financial(123.456));
// Expected output: "123.46"

console.log(financial(0.004));
// Expected output: "0.00"

console.log(financial('1.23e+5'));
// Expected output: "123000.00"
```

Comment: I have tried that  and unable to resolve that.